# StAX escaping of greater than (>)

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am using the StAX Streaming Api in vrsion 1.2.0 from http://stax.codehaus.org/.
When I'm trying to write the following xml to a file the greater than char is not escaped. However lesser than does not seem to have a problem with escaping.

```
out = new FileOutputStream("foo.xml");
XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(out);
writer.writeStartDocument();
writer.writeStartElement("foo");
writer.writeAttribute("test", "<foo>");
writer.writeEndElement();
writer.writeEndDocument();
writer.flush();
writer.close();
out.close();
```

The output (relevant only) is this:

```
<foo test="&lt;foo>"
```

I've also tried to use the writeCharacters method - with the same result. Is this a bug or intention? Is there any workaround? (Replacing > manually by

```
replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
```

results in the '&' getting escaped itself.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it's because you don't *need* to escape `>`. It's already doing the right thing.

Comment: Was just curious about sources like [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/StAX4.html) saying "The writeCharacters(...) method is used to escape characters such as &, <, >, and "."

Comment: @elyan: I suspect it's just overzealous documentation, to be honest. Maybe at one point it *did* (unnecessarily) escape `>`, but now it doesn't.

Comment: @elyan: I've just checked with the spec, and there's one case where it *does* need to be escaped: "The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string " &gt; ", and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either " &gt; " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]> " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section."